# Dynamic html page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, web

Ok, I saw this tutorial http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/, pretty cool actually!
My problem is as flows, I have a page that not only has contents but also specific javascript content, and css. Is there a way to load those files dynamically, would It be correct? What if I have a hard coded on the page, how would I load that css/js script?

Thanks in advance.

[Edit]

Some code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    alert('the document has finished loading!!');
    // do form validation and send
)
</script>
</head>
<body>
Please Full the necesary (*) Fields
<form method="post" action="testing.php" id="test" name="test">
    (*)<input type="text" name="fullname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Let's say I wanna load that page dynamicaly and load the validation and related javascript placed on header. Should load files readeing the headers? how can I know which one had been already loaded?

Thanks for the answers!

"I guess he means hard-coded, static. – Utkanos" - Edited

Comment: Whatever is a 'hard written code'..?

Comment: I guess he means hard-coded, static.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the CSS stylesheet dynamicly by changing the href attribute. 
Javascript can also be loaded dynamicly by loading the script self into the div or by writing the script src to it.

Here an simple example:

CSS 1:

```
body {
    background: black;
    color: #333;
}
```

CSS 2:

```
body {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <link href="/includes/css/test1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>TEST!!!!!</h1>
        <div id="code"></div>
        <input type="button" id="but" value="click!" />

        <script>
            var css = 1;

            $('#but').click(function() {
                if(css == 1) {
                    css = 2;
                } else {
                    css = 1;
                }

                $('link').attr('href', '/includes/css/test' + css + '.css');               

                //test();
                test2();
            });

            function test2() {
                $('#code').html("<script>alert(\"It works!!!\");<\/script>");

                //Or parse the src 
                //$('#code').html("<script src=\"js/your_js_file.js"><\/script>")
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So it's posible to load CSS and Js into your page after the page is loaded.

Hope this helps!